# Map domain to IIS7 virtual directory in localhost

Tags: visual-studio, iis

I have 2 asp.net projects. An API and a web client project. When testing, I need to overcome the same origin policy so I cannot test with them on different ports.

I used visual studio to map the api to: `http://localhost/api` but the other project cannot be mapped to `http://localhost/`. The reason I require it to be the root is because the applications contain references(forms, scripts, etc) to `/` the root. After doing some reading, I need to publish to `wwwroot`, which I dont want to do.

My next option I assume is to map a domain to my virtual directories `http://localhost/web` and `http://localhost/api` => `someDomain.com` and `someDomain.com/api`. How do I do this? Editing the host files doens't work:

```
http://localhost/web    app.com
http://localhost/api    api.app.com
```

Problems (solving either one will work for me):

1. Point `http://localhost/` to `http://localhost/web` to solve the referencing problem.
2. Create my virtual directory in `http://localhost/`;
   [image]
3. Map a domain to the localhost virtual directories.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a "reverse proxy" on localhost to do what you want.

Essentially it will act as a relay - when a client connects to `http://localhost/api`, your proxy can relay that request to `http://somedomain.com/api` then obtain the response, and then pass the response back to the original client. From the client's perspective, the request is being made to localhost, and the response comes from localhost. There is no fiddling with name servers.

[IIS Team's announcement of Reverse Proxy](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/659/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing/)

If you have IIS6 or don't want to use the Microsoft extension, there are other options.
One is [IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com).

Comment: What I eventuall want to do is go to: `localhost` in my browser, and the proxy sends it to `localhost/web`. Is this possible with reverse proxy seeing as I'm trying to use the plain `localhost` root?

Comment: yes; you can do that. You need to be careful about paths to other assets like images, styles and javascripts that are referenced by the html page. But, yes, you can do that.